# Is there a Java web framework that uses Java's security manager for fine-grained security?

Tags: java, servlets

In a standard webapp setting, all code runs with the same privileges.  It would be desirable to follow the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) instead, and Java's security manager (the "sandbox") should in theory make that possible.

I imagine a setting in which the code in a webapp consists of a "front end" whose code is privileged to do only things that the logged-in user is allowed to do, and a "back end" which runs with greater privileges and imposes those limitations on the "front end" code.  Then templates and much of the control logic would be part of the less-privileged "front-end" code, limiting the ways an attacker can compromise security.

Has this already been done?  Is it part of any commonly-used web framework already?

Answer (score 1):

I think Kohsuke's [Stapler](http://stapler.java.net/) framework uses (or can use) a Java security manager, but I can't find a reference for that at the moment. The Stapler framework is great (it's primarily used by Hudson/Jenkins) but the documentation for it is woefully incomplete.